# last letter in first line and and first letter in the next line

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have text file like this:

```
qwery 45
uiopbmc 6
uenja 9999
comxq 8
```

i want to say:

```
mylist=['a','c']
if last letter in the line is 'a' (before the number) and the first letter in the next line is 'c', print both two lines.
```

the result:

```
uenja 9999
comxq 8
```

i know first line in sed like "s/" but how i can say the last letter before the number and first letter in the next line?

Comment: What should the output be if `uenja 9999` was instead `uenja3 9999`? In other words, is it really the first/last letter (`a`) of each first field you care about or is it actually the first/last character (`3`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -n '1N;/a .*\nc/p;N;D'
```

Would report lines containing `"a "` followed by a line starting with `"c"`.

See also:

```
sed -n '1N;/a[^[:alpha:]]*\n[^[:alpha:]]*c/p;N;D'
```

To match on a `a` that is the last *letter*¹ in the first line, and for a second line where the first *letter* is `c`.

Note that on an input like:

```
xa 123
c1a 234
c2a 345
```

it reports both:

```
xa 123
c1a 234
```

and

```
c1a 234
c2a 345
```

Which both match the requirements.

---

<sup>¹ strictly speaking, and despite the *alpha* name, it's not restricted to letters in alphabetic scripts, `[[:alpha:]]` matches on characters that constitute human language words regardless of whether they are alphabetic scripts like Latin or Greek or not like Kanjis... On GNU systems at least, you'll find that it also matches on numeral digits other than 0123456789 to satisfy [conflicting POSIX / C standard requirements](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1078): that alnum = alpha + digit, but that digit be limited to 0123456789 only.</sup>

Comment: thank you, i am sorry, please see the question after i corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```bash
# first field ends with 'a' and next line starts with 'c'
# i.e. current line starts with 'c' and previous line's first field ends with 'a'
$ awk 'p1 ~ /a$/ && /^c/{print p0; print} {p1=$1; p0=$0}' ip.txt
uenja 9999
comxq 8
```

Borrowing input from Stéphane Chazelas's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/715341):

```bash
$ cat ip.txt
xa 123
c1a 234
c2a 345

$ awk 'p1 ~ /a$/ && /^c/{print p0; print} {p1=$1; p0=$0}' ip.txt
xa 123
c1a 234
c1a 234
c2a 345
```

In such cases, the middle line will be printed twice (once as matching `c` at the start and another as matching `a` at the end of first field).

Comment: thank you, i am sorry, please see the question after i corrected it.

Comment: Your code would be clearer if you renamed `p1` (previous value of `$0`) to `p0` and `pf` (previous value of `$1`) to `p1`. IMHO it's worth mentioning that your script will work using any awk in any shell on every Unix box.

Comment: I'm using `pf` as previous field and `pl` as previous line... `p0` and `p1` are nice alternative (`p` instead of `$`)

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -En '/^[^ ]*a/{N;/\nc/p}' input_file
uenja 9999
comxq 8
```